# ¿ por que error al regresar a una pantalla pasando por un AlertDialog?

Tags: excepciones, flutter

Estoy intentando regresar a una pantalla después de realizar una acción pero me manda la siguiente excepción

```
FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)
```

El cual se genera unicamente si paso por un `AlertDialog` que tiene un `FlatButton` y contiene lo siguiente en el `onPressed`

```
{
  Playlist play;
  if (dato != null) {
    play = Playlist(playlistTitulo: namePlaylist, dato: [dato.id]);  
  }else {
    play = Playlist(playlistTitulo: namePlaylist);  
  }
  final result = await playlistBloc.agregarPlay(play);


  if (dato != null) {

    play = await DBProvider.db.getUltimoInsertPlay();
    navigateToDetail(play, context);

  } else {

    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('agregado.'),
    );
    print('snackabar==$snackBar');
    _scaffoldKey.currentState
      .showSnackBar(snackBar);

  }
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
```

Haciendo un seguimiento de la ejecución para ver donde se produce la excepción sucede al entrar en el método `navigateToDetail` y la **excepción** se genera cuando pasa por el siguiente método antes de regresar a la pantalla

```
bool rest = await DBProvider.db.addDatoInPlay(playlist, dato.id,);
```

Tiene la siguiente estructura

```
Future<bool> addDatoInPlay(Playlist play, String idDato) async {
    final db  = await database;
    print('=================::::::${play.idPlaylist}');
    final inser = <String, dynamic>{
      "$_playlistDatoPlaylistId" : play.idPlaylist,
      "$_playlistDatoDatoId"    : idDato,
      "$_playlistDatoOrden"      : 0,
    };
    final res = await db.insert('$tablePlaylistDato', inser);
    final result = await ApiService.addDatoInPlaylist(
      idDato: idDato, 
      tituloPlay: play.playlistTitulo);

    print('Result addDatoInPlay-->$res');
    return res > 0 ? true : false;
  }
```

El cual si quito el `await` de la siguiente linea : `final result = await ApiService.addDatoInPlaylist` ya no marca la esxcepción

por lo tanto esta linea funciona sin problemas

```
Navigator.pop(context, false);
```

Pero yo necesito `await` para poder saber el resultado de esa linea y ver si tiene como resultado un `true` o `false`,
**No entiendo por que con `await` no funciona**

Comment: estas seguro que el error no es en esta linea?  _scaffoldKey.currentState
      .showSnackBar(snackBar);

Comment: Esa función no se ejecuta ya que el dato no viene null, siguiendo la ejecución nunca paso por esas lineas

Comment: Bueno el error dice que estás tratando de usar un widget que ya fue desmontado, revisa bien eso , si tienes alguna referencia a un widget de la pantalla anterior y aún así estás llamandolo

Comment: por eso se me  hace raro, y haciendo muchas pruebas, si quito esta linea. `final result = await playlistBloc.agregarPlay(play);` ya no se genera ninguna excepción y todo funciona como debe

Comment: Tendra que ver con que ese método actualiza la lista de datos que al estar en un `StreamBuilder` recarga un `ListView` que esta dentro de un `Scaffold` que contiene un `RaisedButton` el cual ejecuta el `AlertDialog` y por lo tanto al recargar ya no encuentra el **Widget**

Comment: si lo estás llamando desde otro widget, pues si

Comment: @diegoveloper Ya cambie como esta el `Scaffold` para que siempre sea el mismo, hice muchas pruebas y movimientos y parece no querer funcionar de ninguna forma, supuse que evitando que se recargue el `Scaffold` funcionaria pero no